# DataGrid Selected Item ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I've a ReactiveList Books and was able to bind it to the grid using reactive UI.
I'm trying to get the selected item from datagrid so that I further query the BookService for more detail and show the details in a different grid or in a rowdetail of the datagrid itself.
My ViewModel has following properties

```
    private ReactiveList<Book> books;
    public ReactiveList<Book> Books
    {
        get
        {
            return books;
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref books, value); 
        }
    }
    private string selectedBookName;
    public string SelectedBookName
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedBookName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedBookName, value);
        }
    }
```

And the Book object goes like below

```
public class Book
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public decimal Price{get;set;}
.
.
.//other properties

}
```

I tried to get the selected book's Name and assign it to a SelectedBookName in the constructor of the viewmodel.

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x=>x.Books.ItemChanged).Select(x => selectedBookName= ((Book)x).Name);
```

But this didn't worked for me. Am I missing something or I need to follow the otherway

Comment: Is that a typo or are you using the member variable `selectedBookName` instead of the property?

Comment: Its not typo, I'm assigning the Book.Name to private field selectedBookName

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to bind the datagrid `SelectedItem` directly to a property in the view model which provides access to the entire object

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.SelectedBook, x => x.DataGridBooks.SelectedItem);
```

If you only want the book name then you can used `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see:

1. You are not actually subscribing to the Observable that is listening for changes to the `ReactiveList` so you won't get any updates. You probably want:

---

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x=>x.Books.ItemChanged).Subscribe(x => selectedBookName= ((Book)x).Name);
```

2. If you are assigning to a private member variable then your `ReactiveObject` never knows that the bound property has changed. More likely you mean to do `SelectedBookName = ((Book)x).Name);` Notice the capitalization as you should be assigning to the property if you want the change to notify the bindings.

Comment: this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Books.ItemChanged).Select(x => selectedBookName = ((Book)x).Name); solved the issue